# Only first element in 2D array is being returned - incorrect usage of ReDim?

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array:

```
Dim twod_array() As Variant
```

Which I want to store values from two other arrays: e.g.:

```
Dim arrayone As Variant
arrayone = (1, 2, 3)
Dim arraytwo As Variant
arraytwo = (4, 5, 6)
```

I want to loop through each element of the above arrays and add them in the below manner:

```
Dim count As Long
count = 0
ReDim Preserve twod_array(1,0) // initial sizing
for i = 0 To UBound(arrayone)
    for j = 0 To UBound(arraytwo)
        twod_array(0,count) = arrayone(i) 
        twod_array(1,count) = arraytwo(j)
        count = count + 1
        ReDim Preserve twod_array(1, count) // dynamic resizing (doesnt work)
    Next j
Next i
```

I know at some point I have to ReDim the 2D array which I believe I can do as follows:

```
ReDim Preserve twod_array(1, count)
```

The 1 allows me to specify 2 elements in the x-dimension and the count is incremented because I don't know how many elements each one-d array will have (I just set them equal to three in this example)

For some reason, I can only output the values twod_array(0,0) to twod_array(1,0) and the other ones are blank. I suspect this has to do with how I used ReDim

e.g. right now I'm only getting:

```
twod_array(0,0) = 1
twod_array(1,0) = 4
```

but not:

```
twod_array(0,1) = 1
twod_array(1,1) = 5
```

instead I get:

```
twod_array(0,1) = //blank
twod_array(1,1) = //blank
```

Can someone please help me understand why my code is not resizing the 2D array correctly so I can output all elements it collects?

Comment: There is no redim line in your code.

Comment: If you `ReDim Preserve`, you can resize only the last array dimension.

Comment: @BigBen - You mean if my array has two dimensions, e.g. twod_array(1,2) I can only resize the last one (e.g. 2 in this instance)? 

I really only need to resize the first dimension. Is there a way to do this? Or must I swap the order I add elements to my array?

Comment: See [`ReDim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/redim-statement) docs. Em - maybe you just want a jagged array? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @BigBen - I want to capture data from multiple arrays and sort the results before spitting an output to a new worksheet. I think knowing the limitation I can just change the order I add my values to the 2D array so the size of the last dimension can be changed.

Comment: FWIW resizing an array by +1 at each iteration is terribly inefficient. If you know how many elements you're going to need, size the array up front.

Comment: That's the problem... I wont know how many elements I have until  I analyze each cell in the workbook which may produce arrays of different sizes. That's why I have to keep resizing the 2D array by 1 until I'm ready to take the values it stores and output it into a new spreadsheet.

Comment: How are you analyzing each cell? Hopefully by reading the values into an array first?

Comment: @BigBen - I first loop through a range in a spreadsheet. Then if a cell contains a comma separated list of entries, I split those entries by a comma to create sub-arrays. Every time I have a unique combination of sub-arrays, I increment a counter which corresponds to a new row in a new worksheet. A concatenation of values from various columns are added to the 2D array in the form twod_array(x,y) where one variable represents the count e.g. row in the new worksheet and one represents the column (will be fixed).

Comment: I changed my twod_array to have the dimension that changes last, but even when I ReDim Preserve I only get the output of the first row e.g. twod_array(0, 0) to twod_array(6, 0)  and not the others 

Where the first dimension corresponds to the column number and second dimension corresponds to the row number which I swapped around because the second dimension size in the array will change based on when I determine more rows should be added.

Comment: edited my post for clarity :)

Comment: Collect your array elements into Collection or Dictionary objects. Then you will know the size of the necessary array and can populate it without all the ReDim overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you're after this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub arrays()

    Dim arrayOne As Variant, arrayTwo As Variant
    arrayOne = Array(1, 2, 3)
    arrayTwo = Array(4, 5, 6)

    Dim i As Long
    ReDim twod_array(1, UBound(arrayOne)) As Variant ' array sizing
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrayOne)
        twod_array(0, i) = arrayOne(i)
        twod_array(1, i) = arrayTwo(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

which outputs your desired output:

```
twod_array(0,0) = 1
twod_array(1,0) = 4
```

and

```
twod_array(0,1) = 2
twod_array(1,1) = 5
```

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for. Because the size of each array could be different and I want to iterate through all elements of each one.

Do you know why I can't ReDim inside the loop based on my counter?

Comment: Your question didn't speak about array with different sizes. You may want to reword it as per your real needs and add some meaningful examples, too